# how to generate obfuscated-code

Tags: c, obfuscation, deobfuscation

For example, consider the following code:

```
call far ptr 90b6h:79c35c2eh
shl dword ptr [ebp+0fh],1
db 67h
daa
push eax
push cs
```

How this code block generated in C programming? How can I deobfuscate that code?

Comment: How is this C code?

Comment: Are you looking for a decompiler, which attempts to take a binary image and retrieve the C (or whatever) used to generate it? Or are you looking for a way to add labels to a disassembled program? The code you provided is assembly of which there is a lot of information online about how to read it, too much for a simple answer here.

Comment: to obfuscate like this, you need a tool called "C Compiler". Very difficult to deobfuscate, I am told.

Comment: I want to know how these codes are generated and how can be deobfuscated?(above code is just an example)

Answer (score 5):

It's not obfuscated C code. If this comes from a C program it is a few lines of assembler from a line or so of C code.

Once broken down to assembler it is very difficult to go the other way, especially on an automated basis. While you can get some tools that will do something along those lines the results will not be the original C code but something different that does the same thing. The results will still look obfuscated.

1. **Compiling:** converting high-level language to object code, with perhaps intermediate assembler left over.

   **Disassemble:** Object code to assembler source. This can be done by some programs or debuggers.

   **Decompile:** Converting compiled object code back to the original source language.

What you have is the assembler output of either 1 or 2. You seem to be asking for 3.